# How to use AutoMapper to unflatten DTO to entity/object property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

This is probably a pretty basic question, please excuse my AutoMapper ignorance.  I've tried to figure out the answer from the docs and other SO questions, but failed so far.  Perhaps I'm trying to use AutoMapper to do something I shouldn't.  I want to set a value on an object property from a flattened DTO.

Given these;

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ColourId { get; set; }
    public Colour Colour { get; set; }
}

public class Colour
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FruitDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ColourName { get; set; }
}
```

I can create a flattened DTO no problem,

```
var db = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()
    .ServiceProvider.GetService<FruitDb>();
var fruitDtos = db.Fruits.ProjectTo<FruitDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
foreach (var dto in fruitDtos)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"db fruit {dto.Name} = {dto.ColourName}");
}
```

but when I try and map back from the DTO it's not obvious what I need to do to get the fruit object colour property set, and the Colour.Name set.

```
var exampleDto = new FruitDto()
{
    Name = "lime",
    ColourName = "green"
};
var exampleFruit = _mapper.Map<FruitDto, Fruit>(exampleDto);
Console.WriteLine($"example fruit {exampleFruit.Name} = {exampleFruit.Colour?.Name}");
```

What is the correct approach to get AutoMapper to set exampleFruit.Colour to a new Colour instance with the Name property set (extension to this question, once that is set, how should I then set the colour.Id property if the colour already exists in the db)?

Here is a complete example of the snippets from above;

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace EntityFrameworkAutomapConsole
{
    public class Fruit
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ColourId { get; set; }
        public Colour Colour { get; set; }
    }

    public class Colour
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class FruitDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ColourName { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile));
                    services.AddDbContext<FruitDb>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UseNpgsql("conn string here");
                    });
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }

    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public Worker(
            IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory,
            IMapper mapper)
        {
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
            _mapper = mapper;

            var fruitDb = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()
                .ServiceProvider.GetService<FruitDb>();
            fruitDb.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
        {
            var db = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()
                .ServiceProvider.GetService<FruitDb>();
            var fruitDtos = db.Fruits.ProjectTo<FruitDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
            foreach (var dto in fruitDtos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"db fruit {dto.Name} = {dto.ColourName}");
            }

            var exampleDto = new FruitDto()
            {
                Name = "lime",
                ColourName = "green"
            };
            var exampleFruit = _mapper.Map<FruitDto, Fruit>(exampleDto);
            Console.WriteLine($"example fruit {exampleFruit.Name} = {exampleFruit.Colour?.Name}");
        }
    }
   
    public class FruitDb : DbContext
    {
        public FruitDb(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Colour> Colours { get; set; }
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.HasDefaultSchema("public");

            builder.Entity<Fruit>()
                .HasIndex(f => f.Id)
                .IsUnique();
            builder.Entity<Colour>()
                .HasIndex(c => c.Id)
                .IsUnique();

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }

    public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<FruitDto, Fruit>();
            CreateMap<Fruit, FruitDto>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @lucian-bargaoanu, for the super simple comment.  I missed that in the docs.  So I just need to use ReverseMap() in my Profile and remove the explicit `FruitDto` to `Fruit` map.

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<FruitDto, Fruit>();
        CreateMap<Fruit, FruitDto>();
    }
}
```

becomes

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Fruit, FruitDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```